# Deploy multiple applications in Cherokee and distinguish them by port?

Tags: deployment, port, cherokee, virtualization

I am having an issue on deploying applications with Cherokee web server. The thing is I need to host various Django applications in the same machine and distinguish each one by ports (i.e. app1 in port 8181, app2 in port 8282... you know).

It is very easy to deploy a Django/uWSGI app in Cherokee, as you only need to follow a very simple form and its web interface will do the magic. I can declare all the apps that I want, but I don't find the way to put them to work in a specified port.

Once I entered in Cherokee's admin interface, I have created the ports in the 'General' -> 'Ports to listen' menu. I created all the virtual servers and I added an AND-IP:Port to each rule of its behavior under the 'Behavior' -> 'Rules' menu. I can access one of them when I change the root directory of the 'default' virtual server to it, BUT I can't access the rest of the virtual servers because Cherokee always points me to the server which root directory I have defined in 'default'.

Anyone knows what configuration I missed or can point me to the way to the solution? I checked up Cherokee documentation and a lot of how-tos, but them does not cover this particular issue.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, finally I found it by myself :)

The way is to create a virtual server through the normal form for your application (it does not matter what kind of application is). Then, go to the 'default' virtual server and create a NEW IP/Port rule that match the port you want. Then, in that rule, go to the 'Manager' tab and specify the manager that handles your application.

And that is all :)